# How do I transform this procedural script into a factory or constructor function?

Tags: javascript

So, this is a simple counter script:

```js
//variables
let counter = document.querySelector('.counter');
let decrementCounter = document.querySelector('.decrement-counter');
let incrementCounter = document.querySelector('.increment-counter');
let count = 0;

//event listeners
decrementCounter.addEventListener('click', minusCounter);
incrementCounter.addEventListener('click', plusCounter);

function plusCounter() {
  count++;
  counter.innerHTML = count;
  if (counter.innerHTML > '0') {
    counter.style.color = 'green';
  } else if (counter.innerHTML === '0') {
    counter.style.color = 'black';
  }
}

function minusCounter() {
  count--;
  counter.innerHTML = count;
  if (counter.innerHTML < '0') {
    counter.style.color = 'red';
  } else if (counter.innerHTML === '0') {
    counter.style.color = 'black';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="counter">
    <p>0</p>
  </div>
  <button class="decrement-counter">Decrement</button>
  <button class="increment-counter">Increment</button>
</body>
```

(ignore the bad design, It was just for test purpose)

I wanted to do the same script but with a constructor/factory function. Or just with a simple object(encapsulation).

Maybe I missed something essential and that's why I failed, can someone show me an example of each?

Comment: Please provide more information (a link maybe?) what exactly "a constructor/factory function" and "just with a simple object(encapsulation)" should be. Also provide if you have already tried something and what and why "failed", or if already the start "failed"

Comment: Also if the code does work, consider posting this kind of problem to [code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I didn't knew that a code-review site existed on stackoverflow, thank you. Also, answering your concern:  I just wanted to write that script in a Constructor Function(or other methods like factories) maybe. Object Oriented Programming basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments it is somewhat unclear what sort of encapsulation you are looking for, but here is a simple refactoring of your code into a function which accepts a container element and returns an object containing references to the `set()` function which instantiates your timer functionality on the children of that element, and a `cleanup()` function which removes the instantiation.

It requires that the necessary constituent elements exist within the container, but you could expand on this to either completely build the timer within the function or at least do some checks on the existence of elements so as not to break if they are missing.

```js
const setCounter = (element) => {
  //variables
  const decrementCounter = element.querySelector('.decrement-counter');
  const incrementCounter = element.querySelector('.increment-counter');
  const output = element.querySelector('.output');
  let count = 0;

  function plusCounter () {
    count++;
    output.innerHTML = count;
    if (output.innerHTML > '0') {
        output.style.color = 'green';
    } else if (output.innerHTML === '0') {
        output.style.color = 'black';
    }
  }

  function minusCounter () {
    count--;
    output.innerHTML = count;
    if (output.innerHTML < '0') {
        output.style.color = 'red';
    } else if (output.innerHTML === '0') {
        output.style.color = 'black';
    }
  }
  
  const set = () => {
    decrementCounter.addEventListener('click', minusCounter);
    incrementCounter.addEventListener('click', plusCounter);
    element.classList.add('active');
  }
  
  const cleanup = () => {
    
    decrementCounter.removeEventListener('click', minusCounter);
    incrementCounter.removeEventListener('click', plusCounter);
    count = 0;
    output.innerHTML = "0";
    output.style.color = 'black';
    element.classList.remove('active');
  }
  
  return {
    set: set,
    cleanup: cleanup,
  }
}

const counter = setCounter(document.getElementById('counter-1'));
document.querySelector('.set-counter1').addEventListener('click', counter.set);
document.querySelector('.cleanup-counter1').addEventListener('click', counter.cleanup);

const counter2 = setCounter(document.getElementById('counter-2'));
document.querySelector('.set-counter2').addEventListener('click', counter2.set);
document.querySelector('.cleanup-counter2').addEventListener('click', counter2.cleanup);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.output {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  width: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem auto;
 }
 
 .counter-control {
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
 }
 
 .active {
  background-color: aquamarine;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="counter-1" class="counter">
     <p class="output">0</p>

    <button class="decrement-counter">Decrement</button>
    <button class="increment-counter">Increment</button>
    </div>
    <div class="counter-control">
      <button class="set-counter1">Set Counter</button>
      <button class="cleanup-counter1">Cleanup Counter</button>
    </div>
    <div id="counter-2" class="counter">
     <p class="output">0</p>

    <button class="decrement-counter">Decrement</button>
    <button class="increment-counter">Increment</button>
    </div>
    <div class="counter-control">
      <button class="set-counter2">Set Counter</button>
      <button class="cleanup-counter2">Cleanup Counter</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry If I misguided you. Maybe my Object Oriented Programming knowledge isn't that great :) . Basically I want to write the same script but in an OOP way. (with constructor function for example).

Comment: It seems you are confusing a specific implementation of object oriented programming (classes with explicit constructor functions) for the larger concept.

Comment: I've edited the snippet to add a second timer with a second controller object to illustrate the 'oop' nature of the example. After calling `setCounter()` both `counter` and `counter2` are objects each containing a `set` key and a `cleanup` key but the functions referenced by these keys are specific to each object and only affect the elements they were instantiated with. In the language you are using `setCounter()` is a `factory`  returning a new object on each call.

Comment: Here is a good explanation on Medium [JavaScript Factory Functions with ES6+](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-with-es6-4d224591a8b1) and if you want to specifically work with classes MDN is a good place to start [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems like I have to study more of this if I want to avoid spaghetti code.